# Thread safety and static variables/member functions

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++14, static-initialization

This isn't a question about static initialization and thread safety. They are guaranteed together since C++11 because of the wording used in the standard.
So far, so good. Consider the following class instead:

```
struct S {
    static int id() noexcept {
        static int v = 0;
        return v++;
    }

    template<typename>
    static int value() noexcept {
        static const int v = id();
        return v;
    }
};
```

In this case, two concurrent calls to `S::value<MyType>()` made on different threads are safe (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

Are two concurrent calls like `S::value<AType>()` and `S::value<AnotherType>()` safe as well?

As far as I can see, `value` for itself isn't a problem at all because of the different specializations. However, when it comes to calling `id`, the first line (static initialization) is guaranteed to be thread safe, but the same doesn't apply to the line immediately after.
Therefore, `v` can have the same value for both `AType` and `AnotherType` within `value`.
On the other side, `id` is invoked during static initialization of `v` in `value`, so I'm not that sure about the validity of my *expectation*.
That's why I'm asking. Is there something wrong in my reasoning or the piece of code above isn't thread safe actually?

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to do synchronization, but in your case it is very simple:

```
struct S {
    static int id() noexcept {
        static std::atomic<int> v { 0 };
        return ++v;
    }

    template<typename>
    static int value() noexcept {
        static const int v = id();
        return v;
    }
};
```

Note it is a good practice to avoid post incrementation.

Comment: Avoid post incrementation has the result that 0 is never returned in your case. It isn't something I can accept in the real case actually and `v` is `size_t`. Therefore I cannot avoid post initialization unfortunately.

Comment: You can integrate your question with a mention of `fetch_add` to  maintain post increment behavior.